# How to force push master on a Forked Repo

Tags: git, github

I just got done with a code challenge for an interview. Here's what I did originally:

- Forked from their code challenge repo
- Cloned my forked master
- created a new local branch off that cloned master
- did a ton of commits to it over the past week
- did a ton of PRs from my feature branch back to my forked master

Now that I'm done and they're going to review it.  The goal is to have the whole diff with all of my work visible in a new PR. Here was one suggestion on how to do that from them but I want to be sure I understand it and how to do this.

- make sure that you have a local and remote copy of your code submission branch for safe keeping
- then force push a clean copy of master to your repo
- then your open PR proposing to merge your code submission branch into the clean version of master you just pushed

I'm not really sure what the steps are for doing this.  Do I locally check out master, then do a force push to master?  What would that command look like?

**- then force push a clean copy of master to your repo**
which master are they talking about, my forked repo or the original master I forked from?

I'm a bit lost.  I think they're saying force the original master (master which I forked from) to overwrite my forked master, then do a PR from my forked code submission branch to my forked repo

Am I right to assume this is what I need to do?:

```
git checkout master (because I'm in my feature branch locally currently)
git reset --hard upstream/master  
git push origin master --force (which I assume is the same as this: `git push --force origin`?)
```

Now click the pull request button on my forked repo, change the left to be my forked master and right to be my feature branch for the PR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've done all your work in a feature branch (as it appears you have), you will not need to force push anything because the master branch in your fork will be the same commit as the master branch in the original repo (verify this by comparing the commit hashes). If this is the case, simply open a pull request from your feature branch (in your fork) to master (in your fork) and you're done.

**Edit: nevermind, I didn't read well.**

You do need to force push.

You can do it in a single command, if you know the hash you want to push. Get that hash from the master branch of the company's repo on github. Then:

```
git push -f origin <hash-goes-here>:master
```

Which pushes the hash on the left side of the `:` (the original master commit) to the branch on the right (your master branch), in the repo `origin`. See the full docs for this command here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: no I've done a ton of PRs from my feature branch to my forked master...so I need my forked master to be "reset" essentially to the current state of the master I forked off of originally... so that I can then PR my feature branch to my newly reset forked master

Comment: awesome worked.. Then I just PR'd my forked master (left master, right feature branch for the PR).